# how to verify that a string contains a character

Tags: php

```
$string = "#hello";
```

I'm trying to have `hello` without the `#`. I also want a function to verify if the string contains the `#`.

```
str_replace("#", " ", $string);
```

and neither does

```
strstr($string,"#")
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Perhaps try reading manual first :(.

Comment: How does it not work? https://eval.in/566240

Comment: first if i do if(strstr($string,"#")) it doesn't go into the if statement and second str_replace("#", " ", $string); add a space instead

Comment: Works in my example. You are telling it to add the space. `" "` is a space, do `""` if you want no space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compare the return value to the original.

```
if ($string != str_replace("#", "", $string))
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: @BaptisteArnaud this is what you wanted? `I'm trying to have hello without the #`?

Comment: Just for completeness: you seem to have forgotten to end the clause of the `if` statement with a `)`.

Answer (score 2):

Check the below code:

```
$string = "#hello";
$find = '#';
// verify if the string contains the #
$pos = strpos($string, $find);
// if present replace it
if ($pos !== false) {
    $string = str_replace("#", "", $string);
}
echo $string;
```

Output :
    hello

Comment: Why should the OP "check the code below"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Yeah, but come on, in this ultra simple case, who needs an explanation?!? It really is self-explanatory. Especially with the comments thrown in.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to check if the string contains the character you're looking for in order to use `str_replace`. If the searched character isn't found, `str_replace` will just return your string unmodified.

If you need to see whether or not `'#'` was found after the fact, you can use the optional fourth parameter to `str_replace` that counts the number of replacements:

```
$string = str_replace('#', '', $string, $count);
```

Any number of replacements greater than zero will make the `$count` variable evaluate to boolean `true`, so you can check if replacements were made just by using `if($count)...`

```
if ($count) {
    echo "Replaced $count #s";
    // do whatever you need to do if the string has #
} else {
    echo 'No #s were found.';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with something short, like this:

```
echo strstr($string, '#') != false ? $string = str_replace("#", "", $string) : $string;
```

`strstr()` has to be *tested* in order to determine whether or not you can make a change.